# Make cells visible DataGridView WinForms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Is there any way to make some cells invisible in a `DataGridView` ?

Basically I am making an invoice application in which certain cells have no meaning when a particular setting is used.
I have currently made those cells ReadOnly with no value but it will be cool if they could become invisible/transparent.

Any free 3rd party Control will also do !

Comment: Re-creating Microsoft Excel with the `DataGridView` control is somewhat ill-advised. No, there's no built-in way of hiding individual cells. Microsoft didn't intend for you to re-create Excel.

Comment: Hehe, I am not creating Excel, it's just that in each row there will be 2/3 cells which are of no use and would be better if the user could not see them.

Comment: @Connell I tried to make the BackColor of that cell to Transparent by changing it's cell style but no use :(

Comment: The Control name is not important, If you are aware of any other control that can do what I want, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akshay, think a moment, what does it mean to hide a cell in a grid/table?

you "could" add a whole row or column eventually, a bit like excel allows you to do, but a single cell, what is the expected behaviour?

having a cell set as invisible will still render a rectangle in that location, white over white or black over whatever other combination of back/fore ground colors, you will still see at least a "hole" in the grid.

I don't know a specific way to do it with any grid, setting the cell as read only and clearing the content should help enough, if you really need other things eventually your grid is not well thought for the use you are doing of it, aka should have less rows or columns or should be changed in having multiple smaller grids in the page.

Comment: Maybe the invisible cell takes the color of the form on which the DataGridView is placed ?

Answer (score 2):

At first, I don't think such thing is possible, you can make row or columns invisible. 
The Visible property for cell is readonly and can't be changed in DataGridView, but a guy [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/bb0eefd9-208a-4b67-b461-8276cf3bb7d3/) points out to a custom implementation shown [here](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/2753924/c_datagridview_with_holes/) (no source code provided), essentially what he does is disable the cell and override the OnPaint method of DataGridViewCell.

Comment: Where is that SparseDataGridView ?

Comment: The author didn't provided the source, but pointed out what he did, make cell disabled and then override the OnPaint method

Comment: From the author: "The solution is to make my own SparseDataGridViewCell, derived from DataGridViewTextBoxCell and override OnClick and Paint.
OnClick is for disabling the Mouse and Paint must NOT paint all kinds of things but background and border."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

I don't know what you've tried already, have a look through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx and see if any of the properties could be used as a workaround, particularly the Style property.

Have a look through, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.aspx. Is setting the font color to the same value as the background good enough?

Comment: That's ReadOnly ! MSDN :Gets a value indicating whether the cell is in a row or column that has been hidden.

Comment: read it first before sending... it says: "Gets a value indicating whether the cell is in a row or column that has been hidden." Not exactly what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the forecolor be the same as the background color and don't forget the selectionforecolor to be the same as the selectionbackcolor for each of these cells you wish to hide.

So:

```
MyGrid.rows(0).cells(0).Style.ForeColor = MyGrid.rows(0).cells(0).Style.BackColor
MyGrid.rows(0).cells(0).Style.SelectionForeColor = MyGrid.rows(0).cells(0).Style.SelectionBackColor
```