# Filter by index

Tags: c#

I've tried to make a filter for DataGridView which would show me the row that selected in combobox, but it didn't work out. What should I change in my code?

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert({0}, System.String) LIKE '%{1}%'", dataGridView1.Rows[0].Index, comboBox1.SelectedItem);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

I expected to see row, but I've got empty DataGridView. Thanks.

Comment: There must be [quotes around `System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8#functions), and the first argument to `Convert` is a column name, not a row index.

Comment: @GSerg yes, it works with columns, but how may I get this thing work with index? I need to filter row number, not column value and I can't change database to add new column with numbers. Thanks for the quotes btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide a row in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855155/hide-a-row-in-datagridview)

Comment: @GSerg not exactly my problem. I need filter it with combobox value, not just hide selected rows.

Comment: It shows how to hide specific rows in a datagrid based on index as opposed to column values. The only relevant part is `Rows[row.Index].Visible = false`.

Comment: @GSerg So you suggest me to hide rows that not equal to combobox value by using loop, am I right?

Comment: You are right..

Comment: @GSerg Now it gives me index out of range